# Laravel 5 multi level category

Tags: laravel-5

i currently i have 2 tables `category` & `subcategory` and everything works just fine, but i need another level of sub category which will be like `category->sub->sub` for that matter i tried to find a reasonable solution and i end up with bunch of packages to handle that for me.

## now the question is

1. do i have to delete my category tables and their relations to my
   another modes before i try any package or i should just add package top of my current tables?
2. what is the best package for my purpose base on your experience?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have your project under source control just create a test branch and discard it when you're done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to depend on packages to implement this.

You can design your `categories` table like following:

```
|----------|------------|---------------|
|    id    |    name    |  category_id  |
|----------|------------|---------------|
```

Here `category_id` is nullable field and foreign key referenced to `id` of `categories` table.

For category `category_id` field will be `NULL` and for sub-category `category_id` will be it's parent category id. For sub sub category, `category_id` will be parent sub category id.

In model, you can write relation like following:

Category.php

```
/**
 * Get the sub categories for the category.
 */
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}
```

Now you can get your sub categories like `$category->categories`.

N.B: You don't need the `subcategory` table, Only one table will do the work.

**Update- Show product categories**

Update `Category.php`:

```
/**
 * Get the parent category that owns the category.
 */
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

In `Product.php`:

```
/**
 * Get the category that owns the product.
 */
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Now, you need to get product category and all of its parents. It'll be an array of categories from parents to child. Then you can show as you wish.

```
$category = $product->category;
$categories = [$category];

while (!is_null($category) && !is_null($category = $category->parent)) {
    $categories.unshift($category);
}

// $categories = ['parent category', 'sub category', 'sub sub category' ..]
```

Show category title sequentially

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->title . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: interesting, so for sub sub category(third level) i get id of first level or second level as `category_id`?

Comment: Second level. `category_id` always refers to parent id of category.

Comment: hi, i'm still working on this way that you suggested, i want to know how can i show my post/product categories hierarchy? e.g. i am visiting my product and i want show that this product is under `default category` or `default category->first child` how would i do that? this doesn't work `{{ucfirst($product->category->categories->title)}}`

Comment: hi, if i use you last `foreach` in controller i'll get error and when i'm using it in blade it gives me only category title without any parent.