# when I click category open subcategory but when i click subcategory not open it's subcategory

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
  
<div class="form-group col-md-8">
  <button type="button" class="form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Category  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" >
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <a type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
        </div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
      <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="table">
              <tr>
                  <td style="background-color: green">
                   <div class="col-md-4" >
                    {{-- <a href="#" name="category" id="category" >             --}}
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <option  class="categoryList" value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->category}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                        {{-- </a> --}}
                    </div>
                  </td>
                     <td>
                        <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        <a href="#" name="subcategory" id="subcategory" class="subcategoryList"> </a>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                       <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a href="#" name="subcategorytwo" id="subcategorytwo" ></a>
                        </div>
                     </td>     
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
        
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('.categoryList').on('click', function(){
          //alert('hi');
          var cat_id = $(this).attr('value');
          console.log(cat_id);
          var url = "/api/getSubcategory/"+cat_id;
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: url,
              dataType: "JSON",
              success: function(res)
              {
                // amusing res = {"3":"home","4":"home duplex"}; 
                var html = "";
                $.each(res, function (key, value) {
                     html += "<option value="+key+">"+value+"</option>";
                });
                $("#subcategory").html(html);
              }
          });
        });

    });

  $(function(){
        $('.subcategoryList').on('click', function(){
          //alert('hi');
          var subcat_id = $(this).attr('value');
          console.log(cat_id);
          var url = "/api/getSubcategorytwo/"+subcat_id;
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: url,
              dataType: "JSON",
              success: function(res)
              {
                
                var xxyz = "";
                $.each(res, function (key, value) {
                     xyz += "<option value="+key+">"+value+"</option>";
                });
                $("#subcategorytwo").xyz(xyz);
              }
          });
        });

    });
</script>
@endsection
```

This is my API

```
 public function getSubcategory($id){
    $subcategories = Subcategory::where('category_id',$id)->select('subcategory','id')->pluck('subcategory', 'id');
    return json_encode($subcategories);
  }
   public function getSubcategorytwo($id){
    $subcategorytwos = Subcategorytwo::where('subcategory_id',$id)->select('subcategorytwo','id')->pluck('subcategorytwo', 'id');
    return json_encode($subcategorytwos);
  }
```

This is API route

```
 Route::get('api/getSubcategory/{id}', 'PostController@getSubcategory' );
    Route::get('api/getSubcategorytwo/{id}', 'PostController@getSubcategorytwo' );
```

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJg37.png)

Problem is when i click category open subcategory but when i click subcategory not open his related to subcategory
[This is category table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdTNy.png)

[This is subcategory table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14p0T.png)

[This is subcategorytwo table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i73cz.png)

What is the problem in ajax, even I change variable html replace xyz..
I am giving completely details. Because my English is very poor.
Table, view, controller,route all are defined, when I click category open subcategory, but when I click subcategory it's not opening its related to subcategory.

Comment: What you are seeing in Browser Console?

Comment: console saw only undefined when i click subcategory -@ManzurulHoqueRumi

Comment: Check my complete answer and follow it.

Comment: I apply your answer...even subcategory too not show and console error like this create:1 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952 -@ManzurulHoqueRumi

Comment: You can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34414177/5559590

Comment: my question is different.. i checked and try but not work,,thats why i post question? -@ManzurulHoqueRumi

Comment: How can i append this category in box? -@ManzurulHoqueRumi

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Your table structure is totally wrong. you can use column name like id,parent_id,name. you dont need to create seperate table. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195917/laravel-5-multi-level-category

Answer (score 0):

You are using `a` tag for selecting option. Please use `select` tag like below

```
<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control input-sm">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
         <option  class="categoryList" value="{{$category->id}}"> 
              {{$category->category}}
         </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And for sub category:

```
<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Append subcategory by JS. Then select subcategory and create another `select` and append there.

```
<select name="subcategorytwo" id="subcategorytwo" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

How to append category to `select`

```
let subcat =  $('#subcategory').empty();
$.each(data,function(create,subcatObj){
    let option = $('<option/>', {id:create, value:subcatObj});
    subcat.append('<option value="'+subcatObj+'">'+subcatObj+'</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this method i hope this is helpful for you ,if any problem then ask me again.

```
<select name="category" id="category">
@foreach($categories as $category)
<option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
<select name="subcat" id="subcat">
</select>
<select name="subsubcat" id="subsubcat">
</select>
<script>
$("#category").on('change',function(){
    var id=$(this).val();
   $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'getsubcat/'+id,
      success:function(data){
      $.each(data, function(key,value){   
       $('#subcat')
      .append($("<option></option>")
      .attr("value",value.id)
      .text(value.subcatname)); 
     })
 }
  })

  });
$("#subcat").on('change',function(){
    var id=$(this).val();
   $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'getsubcat2/'+id,
      success:function(data){
      $.each(data, function(key,value){   
       $('#subsubcat')
      .append($("<option></option>")
      .attr("value",value.id)
      .text(value.subsubcatname)); 
     })
 }
  })

  });
</script>
```